# Get event keycode ckeditor 4 react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycode, keyup

I'm struggling right now to get event keycode in ckeditor-4-react
I've read in documentation that the only way to get event keycode is with 
`evt.data.keycode()` but `evt.data` here is undefined

anyone here has any solution ?

[image]

Comment: Which event are you listening to? `change`?

Comment: Mind sharing the code creating and processing the event?

Comment: yes i listen to event change